# smtp;554 5.7.1 NDR error when sending through OWA2003

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

I am having a very strange issue that I have been unable to nail down. When I send to a particular address with Outlook Web Access 2003, I get the NDR message shown below. When I email that same user the exact same email from Outlook 2007 through the same exchange server, I have no bounceback.The user's address is external to our mail server, completely different company.

*Reporting-MTA: dns;xxx.corp Final-Recipient: rfc822;gina@bxxx.com Action: failed Status: 5.7.1 Diagnostic-Code: smtp;554 5.7.1 The message from () with the subject of (Re: Wacom Tab/ Signature Pad) matches a profile the Internet community may consider spam. Please revise your message before resending.*

Does anyone have any idea what would make OWA2003 fail, yet the same message sent through the same server succeed?

Thanks in Advance!
-Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a setting on your end but on the remote server.  On the remote server they probably have some spam filtering settings that give the inbound message a score.  When you send from outlook, the scoring is different than from webmail and due to the the message delivery is changed.

Contact the administrator for the remote domain and have them whitelist your domain.